# Save multiple ggplots as png in zipped folder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how one can save multiple ggplot objects (or others like a csv or txt files) in a zipped folder. I am using the `mtcars` dataset to make two plots (plot1 and plot2) as a reproducible example below. How do I save them in a zipped folder?

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_col(aes(cyl, mpg))

plot2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_col(aes(cyl, disp))
```

Comment: Save them as normal, then zip them. See the `?zip` for details and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_col(aes(cyl, mpg))

plot2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_col(aes(cyl, disp))

ggsave(filename = "plot1.png",
       plot = plot1,
       device = "png")

ggsave(filename = "plot2.png",
       plot = plot2,
       device = "png")

zip("plots.zip", c("plot1.png","plot2.png"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works on Mac but not on Windows 11. Any ideas on how to make it work on WIndows 11?

Comment: @Shubham Can you share any additional info or error message on where things are failing? I am using Windows 11 myself.

Comment: It works on my personal PC. Probably my work computer has some restrictions. Thanks!